# kubernetes cluster master node not ready

Tags: kubernetes

i do not know why ,my master node in not ready status,all pods on cluster run normally, and i use cabernets v1.7.5 ,and network plugin use calico,and os version is "centos7.2.1511"

```
# kubectl get nodes
NAME        STATUS     AGE       VERSION
k8s-node1   Ready      1h        v1.7.5
k8s-node2   NotReady   1h        v1.7.5




# kubectl get all --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                           READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   po/calico-node-11kvm                           2/2       Running   0          33m
kube-system   po/calico-policy-controller-1906845835-1nqjj   1/1       Running   0          33m
kube-system   po/calicoctl                                   1/1       Running   0          33m
kube-system   po/etcd-k8s-node2                              1/1       Running   1          15m
kube-system   po/kube-apiserver-k8s-node2                    1/1       Running   1          15m
kube-system   po/kube-controller-manager-k8s-node2           1/1       Running   2          15m
kube-system   po/kube-dns-2425271678-2mh46                   3/3       Running   0          1h
kube-system   po/kube-proxy-qlmbx                            1/1       Running   1          1h
kube-system   po/kube-proxy-vwh6l                            1/1       Running   0          1h
kube-system   po/kube-scheduler-k8s-node2                    1/1       Running   2          15m

NAMESPACE     NAME             CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
default       svc/kubernetes   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP         1h
kube-system   svc/kube-dns     10.96.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP   1h

NAMESPACE     NAME                              DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system   deploy/calico-policy-controller   1         1         1            1           33m
kube-system   deploy/kube-dns                   1         1         1            1           1h

NAMESPACE     NAME                                     DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
kube-system   rs/calico-policy-controller-1906845835   1         1         1         33m
kube-system   rs/kube-dns-2425271678                   1         1         1         1h
```

---

## update

it seems master node can not recognize the calico network plugin, i use kubeadm to install k8s cluster ,due to kubeadm start etcd on 127.0.0.1:2379 on master node,and calico on other nodes can not talk with etcd,so i modify etcd.yaml as following ,and all calico pods run fine, i do not very familiar with calico ,how to fix it ?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ""
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    component: etcd
    tier: control-plane
  name: etcd
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - etcd
    - --listen-client-urls=http://127.0.0.1:2379,http://10.161.233.80:2379
    - --advertise-client-urls=http://10.161.233.80:2379
    - --data-dir=/var/lib/etcd
    image: gcr.io/google_containers/etcd-amd64:3.0.17
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 8
      httpGet:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        path: /health
        port: 2379
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 15
    name: etcd
    resources: {}
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /etc/ssl/certs
      name: certs
    - mountPath: /var/lib/etcd
      name: etcd
    - mountPath: /etc/kubernetes
      name: k8s
      readOnly: true
  hostNetwork: true
  volumes:
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/ssl/certs
    name: certs
  - hostPath:
      path: /var/lib/etcd
    name: etcd
  - hostPath:
      path: /etc/kubernetes
    name: k8s
status: {}

[root@k8s-node2 calico]# kubectl describe node k8s-node2
Name:                   k8s-node2
Role:
Labels:                 beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                        beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                        kubernetes.io/hostname=k8s-node2
                        node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
Annotations:            node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl=0
                        volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach=true
Taints:                 node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
CreationTimestamp:      Tue, 12 Sep 2017 15:20:57 +0800
Conditions:
  Type                  Status  LastHeartbeatTime                       LastTransitionTime                      Reason                          Message
  ----                  ------  -----------------                       ------------------                      ------                          -------
  OutOfDisk             False   Wed, 13 Sep 2017 10:25:58 +0800         Tue, 12 Sep 2017 15:20:57 +0800         KubeletHasSufficientDisk        kubelet has sufficient disk space available
  MemoryPressure        False   Wed, 13 Sep 2017 10:25:58 +0800         Tue, 12 Sep 2017 15:20:57 +0800         KubeletHasSufficientMemory      kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure          False   Wed, 13 Sep 2017 10:25:58 +0800         Tue, 12 Sep 2017 15:20:57 +0800         KubeletHasNoDiskPressure        kubelet has no disk pressure
  Ready                 False   Wed, 13 Sep 2017 10:25:58 +0800         Tue, 12 Sep 2017 15:20:57 +0800         KubeletNotReady                 runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized
Addresses:
  InternalIP:   10.161.233.80
  Hostname:     k8s-node2
Capacity:
 cpu:           2
 memory:        3618520Ki
 pods:          110
Allocatable:
 cpu:           2
 memory:        3516120Ki
 pods:          110
System Info:
 Machine ID:                    3c6ff97c6fbe4598b53fd04e08937468
 System UUID:                   C6238BF8-8E60-4331-AEEA-6D0BA9106344
 Boot ID:                       84397607-908f-4ff8-8bdc-ff86c364dd32
 Kernel Version:                3.10.0-514.6.2.el7.x86_64
 OS Image:                      CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
 Operating System:              linux
 Architecture:                  amd64
 Container Runtime Version:     docker://1.12.6
 Kubelet Version:               v1.7.5
 Kube-Proxy Version:            v1.7.5
PodCIDR:                        10.68.0.0/24
ExternalID:                     k8s-node2
Non-terminated Pods:            (5 in total)
  Namespace                     Name                                            CPU Requests    CPU Limits      Memory Requests Memory Limits
  ---------                     ----                                            ------------    ----------      --------------- -------------
  kube-system                   etcd-k8s-node2                                  0 (0%)          0 (0%)          0 (0%)          0 (0%)
  kube-system                   kube-apiserver-k8s-node2                        250m (12%)      0 (0%)          0 (0%)          0 (0%)
  kube-system                   kube-controller-manager-k8s-node2               200m (10%)      0 (0%)          0 (0%)          0 (0%)
  kube-system                   kube-proxy-qlmbx                                0 (0%)          0 (0%)          0 (0%)          0 (0%)
  kube-system                   kube-scheduler-k8s-node2                        100m (5%)       0 (0%)          0 (0%)          0 (0%)
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  CPU Requests  CPU Limits      Memory Requests Memory Limits
  ------------  ----------      --------------- -------------
  550m (27%)    0 (0%)          0 (0%)          0 (0%)
Events:         <none>
```

Comment: k8s_node2 is my master node

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about managing your servers can be asked on [sf]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.

Answer (score 18):

It's good practice to run a describe command in order to see what's wrong with your node:

```
kubectl describe nodes <NODE_NAME>
```

e.g.:  kubectl describe nodes k8s-node2
You should be able to start your investigations from there and add more info to this question if needed.

Answer (score 12):

You need install a Network Policy Provider, this is one of supported provider:
[Weave Net for NetworkPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/network-policy-provider/weave-network-policy/). 
command line to install:

```
kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
```

After a few seconds, a Weave Net pod should be running on each Node and any further pods you create will be automatically attached to the Weave network.

Comment: Able to run on master but not on the worker nodes..Getting error..The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refusedThe connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused.. not sure where I need to change - new to Kubernetes

Comment: @AnandKiran this can be due to the fact that there is no kubeconfig file named config at $HOME/.kube

If there's no $HOME/.kube directory, you need to create that manually and copy /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf to this location as "config".

Comment: Running it on master is enough, it will create pods for all the remaining nodes

Comment: The manifest source link is outdated, correct comamnd is now: `kubectl apply -f https://github.com/weaveworks/weave/releases/download/v2.8.1/weave-daemonset-k8s.yaml` according to [the documentation](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kubernetes/kube-addon/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to add tolerations and update the annotations for calico-node in the manifest you are using so that it can run on a master created by kubeadm.  Kubeadm taints the master so that pods cannot run on it unless they have a toleration for that taint.

I believe you are using the https://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.5/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/calico.yaml manifest which has the annotations (that include tolerations) for K8s v1.5, you should check https://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.5/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubeadm/1.6/calico.yaml, it has the toleration syntax for K8s v1.6+.

Here is a snippet from the above with annotations and tolerations

```
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: calico-node
      annotations:
        # Mark this pod as a critical add-on; when enabled, the critical add-on scheduler
        # reserves resources for critical add-on pods so that they can be rescheduled after
        # a failure.  This annotation works in tandem with the toleration below.
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ''
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
      # Allow this pod to be rescheduled while the node is in "critical add-ons only" mode.
      # This, along with the annotation above marks this pod as a critical add-on.
      - key: CriticalAddonsOnly
        operator: Exists
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below process by running the below command:

- **sudo curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add**
- then, Edit sources list file using **nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/Kubernetes.list**
- copy paste the link as below:
  **deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main**
  save and exit from nano file & run **apt-get update** and finally run **apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl kubernetes-cni**

check out kubectl get nodes, now you can see that your control plane/ master is in ready status.

All the best & Regards,
Syed Abid Ali.